# .net application with mysql db error

Tags: mysql, asp.net

This application was working fine in an earlier server and when we ported it to a new server we are getting this issue. What could be the real issue behind this error ? kindly suggest

The error that we get is as follows :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Stream does not support writing.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support writing.

Source Error: 

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

  <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

Stack Trace: 


[NotSupportedException: Stream does not support writing.]
   System.IO.__Error.WriteNotSupported() +56
   System.IO.BufferedStream.WriteByte(Byte value) +43
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PacketWriter.FlushBuffer() +112
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PacketWriter.Flush() +68
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate411() +140
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate() +68
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Reset() +45
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +207
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +52
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager.GetConnection(MySqlConnectionString settings) +228
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +152
   RemoteDB.OpenRemoteDataConnection() +156
   RemoteDB.RemoteRecordFound(String tblname, String fldname, String txt, String SCond) +14
   admin_Default.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +97
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5472; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

---

Appreciate your kind help in resolving this issue. This application is built on mysql db and asp.net version used for this site is 2.0

regards
venkat

Comment: Can you share the code of your `OpenRemoteDataConnection` function